# Need codes to communicate with server from an android phone

Tags: android, gps, communication

I am new to android, and i am trying to develop an app which sends GPS information of current location to a server and retrieve the related information from the database.

Comment: Which server?  An existing one, or do you plan to write a server application too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn the concept of webservices :
and you need to learn the concept of sqlite to store DB locally:

http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

http://ferasferas.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/android-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-sqlite-databases/